# Any way to hide/remove messages in an MS Teams channel?

Tags: microsoft-teams

We recently started using MS Teams and rigged up a web connector to our HR system to notify a specific Teams channel when new accounts are created. Is there any way to remove or hide messages which are X days old?

We used to run this process over XMPP so users could simply type `/clear` in their Jabber client to clear out old messages but with Teams I don't see a way to do that. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for
[Retention policies in Microsoft Teams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/retention-policies):

> Teams retention policies do support:
>
> - Preservation: Keep Teams data for a specified duration and then do nothing
> - Preservation and then delete: Keep Teams data for a specified duration and then delete
> - Deletion: Delete Teams data after a specified duration

You are probably looking for "Preservation and then delete".
See the article for instructions.